How to scroll down for a certain distance with Flutter Test?
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/widget/scrolling
I see that Flutter does provide a function called scrollUntilVisible to let testers use to reach a certain element. But is there a way to scroll down for a certain distance without knowing the feature of the element?
For example, if I wish to take screenshots on a screen with a very long element inside for screenshot testing, I may want to have it scrolled down a bit, take a screenshot, and scroll down a bit again. Elements usually won't allow me to accurately manage the distance I am going to scroll, which makes targeting elements in this use case a bad idea.
BTW, I am aware of the gesture API. But it only works with mobile devices, not desktop browsers.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetController/dragFrom.html
By using this function, you can create your auto-testing with a drag gesture at a certain point on the screen. It won't do anything on the desktop. But if the app is running on a mobile device or a mobile device simulator (e.g. iPad), it can mimic the scrolling behaviour.
